# Looker Studio quota issue with Bigquery and Sheets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, looker

I have a dashboard on Looker Studio free. My data source is BigQuery and Google Sheets.

I receive an error on a chart that says "Error of quota. This dataset has been accessed too many times".

I'm not using Google Analytics as a data source. Any idea how to solve this problem? Do I have to pay for Google Analytics 360? Buy Looker Studio Pro?

Answer (score 0):

GA4 is a native connector of Looker Studio and since it was rolled out and replaced by [GA4 API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1), the [quotas and limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quotas#analytics_property_quotas) became significantly lower.

The possible reason for your quota error is high trafficked data. You can use **GA4 API** to export to `BigQuery` and to lessen the limitation. But the best practice is to migrate from `Standard (free)` to `Google Analytic 360` since you will also have to pay in BigQuery (cheaper). Still, you can use [partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) in BigQuery to increase query optimization and it can help your quota limits.

In regards to `Google Sheets`, you can use it with GA4 API, if you will stick to free and not upgrade to Analytics 360. A connection to Looker Studio can help pull daily data and the API will have a once a day hit with data points.